# Quicksort implementation unclear

Tags: algorithms, sorting, quicksort

This code is taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_sort):

```
// left is the index of the leftmost element of the subarray
  // right is the index of the rightmost element of the subarray (inclusive)
  // number of elements in subarray = right-left+1
  function partition(array, left, right, pivotIndex)
     pivotValue := array[pivotIndex]
     swap array[pivotIndex] and array[right]
     storeIndex := left
     for i from left to right - 1
         if array[i] ≤ pivotValue
             swap array[i] and array[storeIndex]
             storeIndex := storeIndex + 1
     swap array[storeIndex] and array[right]  // Move pivot to its final place
     return storeIndex
```

It is not clear for me why it is true, every iteration storeIndex and i index are pointing to the same place as I see it.

Where am I wrong?
Lets Take for example the array  9,8,6,5
1.pivotIndex I chosen is 0,  hence pivot value is 9.
2.After first swap out array is : 5,8,6,9 (storeIndex point to 0)
3. entering loop left pointing to 0 index, condition happens that is why we swaping on the same cell.
4. i is incremented and pointing to 1, also store index is 1 and so on.

Comment: You example just gives a degenerate case where storeIndex is incremented at every step. Try one with a pivot value that is about in the middle of the values (also, more than four values would give a better idea).

Comment: What's the question?  *"It is not clear for me why it is true"* - what what is true?  I read the entire question and I can't figure out precisely what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A = [5,2,7,6,3,4]$ and $pivotValue=5$. After pushing $5$ to end we get $A=[4,2,7,6,3,5]$. Now when $i=2$, the $storeIndex$ is not changed. Similar is the case for $i=3$. When $i=4$, $A[4]$ and $A[storeIndex]$ get swapped. Note that $storeIndex=2$. So we get $A=[4,2,3,6,7,5]$. You can think $storeIndex$ as a 'marker'. After each iteration of $for$ loop, all values upto 'marker' index are smaller than $pivotValue$.

Comment: First swap happens outside of the loop before incrementing i variable, so i=0 in your case after first swap